# How to get admin inline name or how to define which inline is changed?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 2 inlines with the same model.

```
class UsersInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportsToCriterias

class TeamsInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportsToCriterias

class CTSportsToCriterias(models.Model):
    user_use = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('is available to users?'), default=False)
    team_use = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('is available to teams?'), default=False)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    criteria_group = models.ForeignKey(CriteriaGroups, verbose_name=_('criteria group'))
```

When I remove an item from `UsersInlineAdmin` (so in this case `user_use` is True) and if this item also exists in `TeamsInlineAdmin` (`team_use` is also True), django automatically removes this item from `TeamsInlineAdmin` inline, because according to the Django docs, the code:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
    ...
```

provides model's object.

So, because in my case the model can have some options (`user_use`\ `team_use`), is it possible to get `inline` names in `save_formset` in order to do something like:

```
if (inline_name == 'UsersInlineAdmin' and not obj.team_use) or \
    (inline_name == 'TeamsInlineAdmin' and not obj.user_use):
    obj.delete()
```

?

**EDIT:**
If I add `form` and override `clean()`, when I add a `user` item in case when `team` s item already exists, Django does not update in DB `user_use` to True. Instead Django creates a new record.

```
# admin
class UsersInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportsToCriterias
    form = UserFieldForm

# form
class UserFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CTSportsToCriterias

    def clean(self):
        m = super(UserFieldForm, self).clean()

        # This trick works ok in case when I want to DELETE user's item,
        # so the trick changes in DB 'user_use' to False, if 'team_use' already exists
        if m['DELETE'] is True:
            try:
                qs = CTSportsToCriterias.objects.get(object_id=object_id,
                                                    content_type=content_type,
                                                    criteria_group=criteria_group,
                                                    team_use=True)
                m['id'] = qs.pk
                m['DELETE'] = m['user_use'] = False

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass

        # Can not repeate the same trick as above. 
        # When 'team_use' already exists, I want to change the value 'user_use' of this team's obj to True,
        # but the trick as above does not work in this case - Django adds a new row to DB, instead of update
        # the existing one.
        elif m['DELETE'] is False:
            try:
                qs = CTSportsToCriterias.objects.get(object_id=object_id,
                                                      content_type=content_type,
                                                      criteria_group=criteria_group,
                                                      team_use=True)
                m['id'] = qs.pk
                m['DELETE'] = m['user_use'] = False

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass

        return m
```

Comment: Can't you do it on the form level? Make a form for `UsersInlineAdmin` and `TeamsInlineAdmin` that does the check in the `clean()` method for example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @makaveli, do you mean to add `form=UserFieldForm` to `UsersInlineAdmin` and write `class UserFieldForm(forms.ModelForm): class Meta: ... def clean(self): ...do something.. super(...).clean()`? I tried this and clean() is not called.

Comment: Yes, I mean that and it will get called, once you do everything correctly. :) I just wrote the same thing today and it works fine. Asking the stupid questions, but do you know that the `clean()` method gets called once you hit save? It's not called on load. But in some 15-20 minutes I can also give you a working example.

Comment: @makaveli, just checked again :) I have a lot of forms and I tried to override wrong form class :) Now clean() is called as expected and will try to get what I need.

Comment: Nice, let me know if it doesn't work out for some reason.

Comment: @makaveli, I have made as you suggested. Could you help me a bit to solve this issue? I updated my problem with new info.

Comment: Well, is the `EXISTS` printed out or not? Also you should return the cleaned data from clean method as `return self.cleaned_data`, but that shouldn't interfere with the `update()` not working.

Comment: @makaveli, yes - `Exists` is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# forms
class UserFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_use = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=True, required=True)

    def clean(self):
        m = super(UserFieldForm, self).clean()

        if m['DELETE'] is True:
            m['user_use'] = False

        return m

class TeamFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team_use = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=True, required=True)

    def clean(self):
        m = super(TeamFieldForm, self).clean()

        if m['DELETE'] is True:
            m['team_use'] = False

        return m


# admin
class UsersInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportsToCriterias
    form = UserFieldForm

class TeamsInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = CTSportsToCriterias
    form = TeamFieldForm


class CriteriaGroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaTranslationsInlineAdmin, UsersInlineAdmin, TeamFieldForm]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)

        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            if isinstance(instance, CTSportsToCriterias):
                is_user_use_form = obj.user_use
                is_team_use_form = obj.team_use

                # There is just one option in DB (user_use or team_use), so delete obj from DB
                if not is_user_use_form and not is_team_use_form:
                    obj.delete()

                else:
                    user_n_team = CTSportsToCriterias.objects.get(
                        object_id=obj.object_id, content_type=obj.content_type, criteria_group=obj.criteria_group)

                    # Means 'user_use' exists and we need to change 'team_use' to False
                    if is_user_use_form:
                        user_n_team.team_use = False

                    # Means 'team_use' exists and we need to change 'user_use' to False
                    elif is_team_use_form:
                        user_n_team.user_use = False

                    user_n_team.save()

        # Saves user_use + team_use in one row as there is no need to use 2 DB rows for each case (user\team)
        # if user_use or team_use already exists in DB, or just creates a new row.
        for instance in instances:
            if isinstance(instance, CTSportsToCriterias):
                content_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=instance.content_type_id)
                criteria_group = CriteriaGroups.objects.get(id=instance.criteria_group_id)

                qs_kwargs = dict(content_type=content_type, object_id=instance.object_id, criteria_group=criteria_group)

                is_user_use = instance.user_use
                is_team_use = instance.team_use

                if is_user_use:
                    qs_kwargs.update(defaults=dict(user_use=is_user_use))
                if is_team_use:
                    qs_kwargs.update(defaults=dict(team_use=is_team_use))

                CTSportsToCriterias.objects.update_or_create(**qs_kwargs)
```